# Connect 2 vertices with a cylinder

Tags: vertices, snapping

I'm working on a chemistry project where I want to create some atomic structure.
In order words, I have two atoms and I want to connect their centers with a bond (cylinder).
[image]
I was thinking about snapping tools but the cylinder can only have 1 origin so its two ends cannot snap to the two vertices.

Comment: does the connection need to seem welded or is this good: https://zupimages.net/up/23/20/ls4r.jpg

Comment: @moonboots what in the picture looks good to me. I just have many bonds to make so I'm wondering if there's a way to snap them automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your 2 spheres, create a curve, in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Vector* in order to flatten, put its 2 ends at the centers of the spheres, give it thickness in the *Object Data > Geometry > Bevel > Depth*, give it 2 *Hook* modifiers with the spheres as *Object*:

[image]

If you move the spheres the curve sticks to the centers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Geometry Nodes setup like so:

[image]